# Can I use the Kleene plus in the lookbehind in regexp

Tags: php, regex

Can I use the Kleene plus in the lookbehind in regexp?

What is the problem with this regular expression?

```
(?<=\[\[\w+\-).+(?=\]\])
```

If I want to select for example "hello" in this text

```
avaavasda sfdsfdf [[anything-hello]] dsfsdf sfsdfdsf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO you can't have a variable lookbehind, but you can do this in php:

```
\[\[\w+-\K[^\]]+(?=]])
```

the \K is like an amnesia pill (forget all that you have seen before me)

Comment: @faressoft: I have read to quickly your question, see my edit

Comment: @faressoft: \K = forget all before me, but you can do some captures before if you want

Comment: @faressoft: yes the lookahead (that can be variable length)